# Remote chaincode install fails

Tags: installation, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have downloaded Fabric 1.0 from official docker hub and run it, runs local chain code successful, but I want to install remote HTTP chain code, for example from `github.com`

This is my command in CLI:

```
peer chaincode install -n devincc -v 1.0 -p https://raw.githubusercontent.com/studyzy/ChainCode/master/chaincode_example02/chaincode_example02.go
```

or:

```
peer chaincode install -n devincc -v 1.0 -p https://github.com/studyzy/ChainCode
```

All of them didn't work, show log:

> 2017-06-22 08:00:57.043 UTC [golang-platform] getCodeFromFS -> DEBU 006 getCodeFromFS https://github.com/studyzy/ChainCode/example02
>   Error: Error getting chaincode code chaincode: Error getting chaincode package bytes: Error getting code code does not exist Could not open file open /opt/gopath/src/https:/github.com/studyzy/ChainCode/example02: no such file or directory

Does there have any command to install URL chain code?

Answer (score 1):

Fabric 1.0 does not support remote  paths (the "http://" in the "-p" option value). The packaging is now all in the CLI, ie, client side and developer should have the code in the GOPATH.

Comment: When you start up your network, you define where is your chaincode. You do this via the docker-compose-cli.yaml file. Then, the CLI Docker container is created copying all the chaincodes that were allocated in the directory that you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

While @Mark P, is absolutely correct about the fact that Hyperledger doesn't support installation of remote chaincodes, e.g. http, https. You still can have remote chaincode installed by explicitly calling to:

```
go get https://github.com/studyzy/ChainCode
```

and then

```
peer chaincode install -n devincc -v 1.0 -p github.com/studyzy/ChainCode
```

all you need is to have chaincode on your `GOPATH`.